# Youtube video not playing in firefox after storing the embed-code in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, youtube, embed

The problem is as described in the title. I'm using C#, MVC3, Entity Framework and SQL Server.

When exposing the data in the view I use `@Html.Raw(Model.Code)` which renders the html exactly as expected. The problem is that there's no video, only a black div.

This is the rendered Html:

```
<iframe width="400" height="225" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PjWktOLFFuA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It works as normal in all other browsers. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the resulting relevant HTML.

Comment: Posted the resulting HTML

Comment: If it doesn't work after being stored in sql server - that means you've broken it in some way. Take the original and compare to what is generated on the page with sql server (I wonder it wasn't obvious for you)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the feedback. Yes, I've done that. What's odd is that all browsers renders it perfectly, it seems to be a Firefox-specific problem. Another thing worth mentioning is that if I paste the same code in the same page (except not using the @Html.Raw()) it works fine.

Comment: @PuffyChair: there is no difference from where the embed code came from - either statically inserted or retrieved from database. If there is different behaviour - then the html code is different.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It was css related. The wrapping div was a part of the isotope.js plugin and the following property was added to the div causing it not to be displayed in Firefox.

```
transform: translate(0px, 0px);
```